# How to get circle markerimage google map in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

```
var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage( images/beachflag.png );

var marker = new google.maps.Marker ({ map: googleMapComp, position: storeResult_coords, icon: markerImage, title: title, animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Cutomize Google Map marker with Rounded shape**

According to this example,

I was able to implement this successfully https://jsfiddle.net/uaxb76f8/12/

```
  .gm-style img {
     max-width: none;
     border-radius: 25px !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-predefined your icon should be like this:

```
icon: {
  path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
  scale: 10
}
```

Did I understand your problem correctly?

Comment: Thank you, But i want to custom icon in marker.                                             var marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
 map: map,
 position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.809177, -84.412636),
 icon: 'http://the99apps.com/dmindia/testimg.jpg',
 title: 'MapImage', 
animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
 });

Comment: OK, I don't quite understand your requirements. Based on this example, can you explain what doesn't work for you? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex

Comment: var image = {
    url: 'images/beachflag.png',
    
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  };

I used this code segment to get the custom images on map as marker. The Image currently appear in square format(as given in above link), but I want this to be in Rounded format.